# Append and insert element into list in one line?

Tags: python

Try to solve task from begginers set, subject "Lists"

My list looks like:
`f = ["apple", "pear", "cherry"]`

I need to add "peach" after "pear", and after "cherry". The task is to write code in a single line.

I tried:

```
f.append("peach").insert(2, "peach") #error
f.insert(2, "peach").append("peach") #error

f[2:] = ["peach", "cherry", "peach"] # incorrect answer
f.insert(2, "peach") ; f.append("peach") # incorrect answer
```

No for, or other loops **only array methods**. I have no idea how to do that?
Maybe, I can use `insert()` some how to insert "peach" twice into two different indexes?

Comment: I'm not sure where the "challenge" is from, but I'll just mention this so you don't get the wrong idea: trying to shove everything into one line is not a good goal to have. If something needs multiple lines, write it over multiple lines.

Comment: I know how to do this in 2 lines, but this is a task with auto-checker :D

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen peach should be there twice

Answer (score 0):

Without cheap hacks like putting in a semi-colon to put two logical lines on a single line, the best options I can come up with are:

```
# Unpacking assignment to shove it in both places, one after another
f[2:2], f[4:] = [['peach']]*2
```

or:

```
# Pop off last element, then extend with last element surrounded by new elements
f += ['peach', f.pop(), 'peach']
```

To be clear, I would never do either of these in real code; the second option may be "less terrible", but the correct solution is a two-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to slice:

```
f = ["apple", "pear", "cherry"]
f[2:] = ["peach", f[2], "peach"]
print(f)
```

The output:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'cherry', 'peach']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple options, as you can see from the answers. Another on:

```
f = f[:-1] + ["peach", f[-1], "peach"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow ugly, but logically correct and does the work:

```py
sum(([x, 'peach'] if x in {'pear', 'cherry'} else [x]  for x in f), [])
```

Comment: we have no `for` to use, only list methods

Answer (score 0):

```
f[2:4] = ["peach","cherry","peach"]
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'pear', 'peach', 'cherry', 'peach']
```

Comment: this code is incorrect for checker, slicing is not an answer